# How to make div the same height as two divs

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a sidebar div the same height as two divs.
These two divs are the top banner image, and the main page content (that floats left) below.

Below is my attempt:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#zeroey").height( jQuery("#page").height() + jQuery("#page-header-img").height() );
});
```

However, this makes the sidebar nearly twice the size of all of the content.
I've already tried wrapping the two divs into one conatiner, however the height is still off by almost 1 third..

See http://deset.me/avenir/

Is there an easier solution to this?

Comment: Try to set it in `$(window).load()` just to see what happen.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've just tested this, however it's still the same results.